# How to prevent Kohana 3.1's ORM to use Auth?

Tags: orm, kohana, authentication

The Auth module of Kohana 3.1 is broken so I need to implement mine. However, it seems that when I disable the Auth module, the ORM is still using it. i.e. it's going to try to apply Auth::hash on passwords, load orm/auth/user.php when trying to access users, etc.

Is there any way to prevent it from doing that and let me manage my own users and roles tables?

Comment: If you disabled Auth module - then it is disabled, obviously. ORM itself doesn't know about Auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the Auth module and extend ORM directly in your models on application level (Model_User, Model_Role).